# XPath to get all sub-nodes & values

Tags: java, json, xml, xpath, nodes

I am trying to get all of the activities and their child nodes from the following XML source.

```
<process>
  <name>processName</name>
  <input>JSON</input>
  <input>productName</input>
  <output>JSON</output>
  <activity>
    <name>createDomain</name>
    <type>bean</type>
    <input>domainName</input>
    <output>JSON</output>
  </activity>
  <mapActivity>
    <map></map>
  </mapActivity>
  <activity>
    <name>preFill</name>
    <type>REST</type>
    <input>JSON</input>
    <output>JSON</output>
  </activity>
</process>
```

So the result would return `createDomain, bean, domainName, JSON` and `preFill, REST, JSON, JSON`. But I am unsure how to go about this.

I have this code currently.

```
    public static void displayActivities(Document myDoc) throws Exception {
    XPathExpression exp = xp.compile("process/activity/*");
    NodeList myList = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(myDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node tempNode = myList.item(i);
        System.out.println("Value: " + tempNode.getNodeValue());
        if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < tempNode.getChildNodes().getLength(); x++) {
                System.out.println("Sub-value: " + myDoc.getChildNodes().item(x).getNodeName());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
}
```

This returns the following:

```
Value: null
Sub-value: process
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the DOM in Java everything is a Node.  The element is a node, the text is a node and so on and so forth.  Your XPath will return the full XML elements:

- <name>createDomain</name>
- <type></type>
- <input>JSON</input>
- <output>JSON</output>

Meaning that tempNode is actually of type Element, not text.  You will find the Text in a child node.  According to the [Node Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) Elements will return null when getNodeValue() is called.